# Tkinter runtime error maximum recursion when open a window

Tags: python, tkinter, runtime, tkinter-canvas

I actually have a big problem.
I already have a tkinter window and I want to open an other.

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import threading, time
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from record_pd import *

class Gui_Record(Tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self, tkroot):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Enregistreur")
        #self.root.geometry()                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        self.root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (500, 70, 400, 300))
        self.root.c = Canvas(tkroot, bg='black')
        self.root.c.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        self.initialize()
        self.recorder = RecordPd(tkroot)
        self.recorder.init_recorder()

    def initialize(self):
        #self.root.grid()                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

        self.root.resizable(False, False)

        self.Imgtmp = PhotoImage(file="img/record.png")
        self.imgclear = PhotoImage(file="img/clear.png")

        self.root.title = Tkinter.Label(self.root, text="Enregistreur Orgue Sensoriel", bg="black", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 16))

        self.root.title.pack()

        self.root.button = Tkinter.Button(self, command=self.OnButtonClick, bg="black", bd=0)

        self.root.button.config(highlightthickness=0)
        self.root.button.config(activebackground="black")

        self.root.button.config(image=self.Imgtmp)
        self.root.button.pack()

        self.root.bind("<Destroy>", self._onDestroy)
        self.resume = True
        self.activate = False


    def setTkroot(self, tkroot):
        self.tkroot = tkroot

    def _onDestroy(self, e):
        self.resume = False
        self.recorder.stop_recording()


    def OnButtonClick(self):
       if (self.activate == False):
            self.resume = True
            self.recorder.open_wav()
            self.recorder.start_recording()
            thread = threading.Thread(target=self.threadClignoter)
            thread.start()
            self.activate = True
            print("In recording..")
       else:
            self.stopThread()
            self.recorder.stop_recording()
            self.activate = False

    def threadClignoter(self):
      isVisible = True

      while self.resume:
            if isVisible:
                clr = self.imgclear
            else:
                clr = self.Imgtmp

            self.root.button.config(image=clr)
            isVisible = not isVisible
            time.sleep(0.5)

    def stopThread(self):
        print("Record done.")
        self.resume = False
        self.root.button.config(image=self.Imgtmp)
```

When I call my object I do:

```
rec = Gui_Record(self.tkroot)
rec.mainloop()
```

When I launch a single window it's okay. But when i add my new window to my parent window it happened that:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/naqued/Documents/assembla/backup/naqued-s-space/stido/gui_stido.py", line 139, in launch_recorder
    app = Gui_Record(self.tkroot)
  File "/home/naqued/Documents/assembla/backup/naqued-s-space/stido/record_gui.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.initialize()
  File "/home/naqued/Documents/assembla/backup/naqued-s-space/stido/record_gui.py", line 35, in initialize
    self.root.button = Tkinter.Button(self, command=self.OnButtonClick, bg="black", bd=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2128, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2049, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2022, in _setup
    if not master:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1848, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr
.... ... ... ... .. .. ... 
  return getattr(self.tk, attr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1848, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1848, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1848, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1848, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I don't do recursion on my code.
I don't know what happened and didn't find anything in the web.

Comment: what does sys.getrecursionlimit() return ?

Comment: i have fix the problem, i will post my code in a few hour :)

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a class that inherits from `Tk`, but it *also* creates a new instance of `Tk`, and even though you don't show it you're *also* creating another root at some point (the object being passed in as `tkroot`) I'm not sure if that's the *only* problem, but it's definitely *a* problem.

Since this is a secondary window, you shouldn't be inheriting from `Tkinter.Tk`. Instead, inherit from `Tkinter.Toplevel`

You also have the problem that even though this creates a new window as a child of `tkroot`, some of the internal widgets are being created as children of `tkroot` so they won't appear in this window.

You also need to fix  your imports -- you shouldn't be doing a global import from `Tk` and *also* importing `Tk` as a module.

You're likely going to have other problems. Tkinter doesn't work well with threads. I've heard that it sometimes works on linux, but in general you should never call any GUI function from any thread other than the one in which the widget was created.

Comment: Thx, you'r answer is very interessting.

i understand my mistake. i use now Tkinter.Toplevel, because as i read. it's the best way to create an other window.

yeah i need to fix my import too.

There was an other problem of recursion, because i recall mainloop() (2 mainloop() in my code)

i will post my code in a few hour

Comment: @Naqued: your program should only ever have a single call to `mainloop`

Comment: Can a bad import caused a "runtime error, maximum recursion.." i actually call a object méthode, when i call it, my program have a runtime error, when i comment the call, my program work..
i'm going to learn some tips with import in python

Comment: @Naqued: Can a bad import cause a maximum recursion error? Yes. When you import a module, code inside gets executed. If there's buggy code in the module you can get errors.